# Why isn't mysqli_connect working but mysql_connect is?

Tags: php, mysql

Are there any reasons why this might be the case?

Here's the code:

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
echo $dbc;
if(!$dbc){
die('could not open a connection'.mysqli_connect_errno() . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Again, if I replace mysqli with mysql I get a returned dbc resource id (I assume that's good). I would like to use mysqli as I hear it's much better/faster. Right now I'm getting error code 2003.

Comment: If you can you should actually use [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) over `Mysqli`... Its also much easier to work with in terms of prepared statements and some other things :-)

Comment: instead of die() call mysqli_error to get the error message. You should also understand the differences between the methods beyond mysqli is "better".

Comment: I second prodigitalson's comment of using PDO

Comment: I gotta second the use of PDO.  It will make your life much better.  Drop mysqli_connect and mysql_connect like hot iron.  Now, there is a little overhead in terms of complexity, but if you get the understanding you can write yourself a slick function wrapper for PDO to make it trivially usable.

Comment: Yeah, also don't get in the habit of using die() on mysql failures, it can quickly attract sql-injection kiddies.  I found that one out the hard way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysql_connect()` and `mysqli_connect()` use two different default ports from the php.ini file. I wouldn't guess that these would be different than the standard default 3306, but worth a check or try adding the path to the host url.

[mysqli_connect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php):

> mysqli mysqli_connect ( ... int $port = ini_get("**mysqli.default_port**") ... )

[mysql_connect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php):

> If the PHP directive **mysql.default_host** is undefined (default), then the default value is 'localhost:3306'. In SQL safe mode, this parameter is ignored and value 'localhost:3306' is always used.

Edit: I was wrong because I didn't read the manual page far enough.

<strike>I think your connection is fine, but you wouldn't want to check the object it returns as you have above. You'd want to use `mysqli_connect_errno()`. Below is the example from PHP.net.</strike>

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

> **Note:**
> OO syntax only: If a connection
>   fails an object is still returned. To
>   check if the connection failed then
>   use either the mysqli_connect_error()
>   function or the mysqli->connect_error
>   property as in the preceding examples.

[Source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)

Comment: Sorry not really following your new answer. What exactly would the new mysqli_connect call look like?

Comment: $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_PORT);

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it helped me solve my problem. I figured out that both were using port 3306, but my problem was I used the server ip address instead of `localhost` for the DB_HOST parameter, which was preventing the connection from working for some reason. Hopefully this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

[mysqli_connect](http://php.net/mysqli_connect) and [mysql_connect](http://php.net/mysql_connect) take different parameters and return different values.

Comment: I don't think they do if you use procedural coding style

Comment: @cfarm54: According to the documentation linked above, the fourth parameter of mysqli_connect (OOP and procedural version) is 'dbname' nd an object is returned in both cases. I was unable to find any documentation that made the fourth parameter match mysql_connect()'s 'new_link'. Can you?

Comment: No idea but it seems to work if I just replace mysqli with mysql. It still returns a resource id so this isn't the solution.

Answer (score 0):

consider using

```
$dbc= new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
```